# VB.net LINQ Left Join with all results

Tags: vb.net, linq, join, left-join

I couldn't find a solution that works in the current .net version.

I have a list of orders and I have a list of additional information for SOME order. (The order either could or could not have additional information).
I'm looking for how to show ALL ORDERS and additional information (if it exists).

I'm trying this:

```
       Dim res = From k In o.OrdemItens
          Join r In aditionalInformation On r.idReqCTP Equals k.Controle
          Group By k.Controle Into Group
          From g In Group.DefaultIfEmpty
          Select g.k.Controle, g.r.Status
```

But it's not working. When the order doesn't have additional information nothing is returned.

Could someone help me plz?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use a `Group Join` which is explicit in VB:

```
Dim res = From k In o.OrdemItens
          Group Join r In aditionalInformation On r.idReqCTP Equals k.Controle Into rj = Group
          Select k.Controle, Statuses = (From r2 In rj Select r2.Status)
```

I didn't know if you might have multiple matches in `rj` for a given `k`, so I ran a `Select` against it.

If you don't want a list in Statuses, you can flatten it out:

```
Dim res = From k In o.OrdemItens
          Group Join r In aditionalInformation On r.idReqCTP Equals k.Controle Into rj = Group
          From r2 in rj.DefaultIfEmpty()
          Select k.Controle, r2?.Status
```

You can't use `?.` for a database so you have to do:

```
Dim res = From k In o.OrdemItens
          Group Join r In aditionalInformation On r.idReqCTP Equals k.Controle Into rj = Group
          From r2 in rj.DefaultIfEmpty()
          Select k.Controle, Status = If(r2 Is Nothing, Nothing, r2.Status)
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked.
I had to add "... into rj = Group..." to work as well.

Comment: Sorry about that - mostly a C# user.